# Is it possible to use flashvars with JBoss?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, fusioncharts

I'm part of a team developing a product using JSF 2.0 and I was asked to investigate the possibility of including FusionCharts free in the app. I have tried different ways of inserting a simple chart in a JSF page but with no luck.

On of the methods involves using the elements OBJECT and EMBED but hhen I try to use them I get a "null source" error from JBoss. From what I could find online (through Google), I am under the impression that 'flashvars' isn't quite compatible with JBoss. Is anyone here able to confirm this? If this is the case, what workaround would you suggest me?

Other ways I also found online didn't show the chart not even an error message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what the other methods quoted were, but the preferred way of embedding flash is to use swfobject, a javascript library that does not require any special tags (nor server-side support).

It boils down to preparing a div for your flash content, giving it an id, and then calling a single function that takes the swf file url, size of the clip, flasvars and so. The javascript could easily contain EL expressions.

You might want to read this:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html

but skip to the *Under the hood: dynamic publishing* section, you will not be using the static publishing nor GUI.

Comment: Thank you for your tip fdreger. I'll look it up. While I was looking for a way of solving my problem I also found a taglib that made it possible to include a flash chart using JSF tags. Currently I'm using JSF 2.0 and FusionCharts (for the flash charts). If anyone else needs help with this integration I'll provide any help I can.

Answer (score 0):

The probable solution might be to pass the value of the flashvars as querystring of the user loading the chart swf file.

e.g.,

```
Column3D.swf?debugMode=1&dataURL=mydata.xml&registerWithJS=1&chartWidth=200&chartHeight=300
```